# Typescript, self returning generic

Tags: javascript, generics, interface, typescript

I'm working on a class that implements a generic interface like:

```
interface World<T> { get(): T; }
class Hello implements World< Hello > { get(){ return this } }
```

But then I was thinking that what if another class than `Hello` will implement `World` interface, intead of having a to use `World< AnotherClass >` I was thinking about something like `World< World >` so it can be permanent wherever I implement the `World` interface, but it looks like Typescript don't accept that syntax, is there any better way to do so?, maybe there is a way around it?

Comment: Are you looking for the TypeScript equivalent of the Singleton pattern?  As in, there's only ever one instance of the World class and get() accesses that instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry but it's not clear what you mean by "so it can be permanent wherever I implement the World interface".  Maybe you just want a non-generic interface?

```
interface World {
  get(): World;
}

class Hello implements World {
  get() {
    return this;
  }
  hello() {
    console.log("hello");
  }
}

class AnotherClass implements World {
  get() {
    return this;
  }
  anotherClass() {
    console.log("another class");
  }
}

var h = new Hello();
var ac = new AnotherClass();

var testH = h.get();  //testH is implicitly typed as Hello
var testAC = ac.get();  //testAC is implicitly typed as AnotherClass

//these all work.
var testWorld : World;
testWorld = h.get();
testWorld = ac.get();
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being vague, you perfectly understood me, my head was stuck upon generics, thank you.